# printf outputs too often

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>


void fillline(char *line, char c, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i<len-1; i++)
        line[i] = c;
    line[len-1] = '\n';
    line[len] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    
    char xs[4][30];
    fillline(xs[0], '-', 30);
    fillline(xs[1], '(', 30);
    fillline(xs[2], ')', 30);
    fillline(xs[3], 'Z', 30);

    printf("%s", xs[0]);
    printf("%s", xs[1]);
    printf("%s", xs[2]);
    printf("%s", xs[3]);
       
}
```

Hello, C-programming newbie here. I have a problem with the code above. I expect

```
-----------------------------
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

as command-line output generated from my code, but I get

```
-----------------------------
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried `fflush(stdout)` and `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` (although I am definitely not sure that this is a `stdout`-problem).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have not allowed room for a null-terminator to your strings. Consequently each one flows into the next. If you look carefully at the output pattern, first all 4 are printed, then 3, 2, and 1.

Comment: `line[len] = '\0'` should raise red flags. You can't assign to an index equal to the length of the string. `len - 1` is the last valid index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of two reasons.

1. The strings ain't got a null terminator. Using it as string in `printf("%s", xs[N])` causes undefined behavior.
2. With

   ```
   line[len] = '\0';
   ```

   you also attempt to write `'\0'` into an not existing 31th element.

Note that array indexing starts at `0`, not `1`. This confusion is what caused your trouble here.

Both things, the use of an indeterminate string and writing beyond the bounds of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).

---

Solution(s):

#### 1.

Change

```
void fillline(char *line, char c, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
        line[i] = c;
    line[len-1] = '\n';
    line[len] = '\0';
}
```

to

```
void fillline(char *line, char c, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len-2; i++)
        line[i] = c;
    line[len-2] = '\n';
    line[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

OR

#### 2.

Decrement `len` before the use in the loop by `1`.

```
void fillline(char *line, char c, int len) {
    len--;
    for(int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
        line[i] = c;
    line[len-1] = '\n';
    line[len] = '\0';
}
```

OR

#### 3.

Call the function `fillline` with an third argument of value `29`, not `30`.

```
fillline(xs[0], '-', 29);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the end of your buffer.

```
void fillline(char *line, char c, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i<len-3; i++)
        line[i] = c;
    line[len-2] = '\n';
    line[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `< len - 3` needs to be `<= len - 3` OR `< len - 2`. Otherwise also UB.

Answer (score 1):

That is no `'\0'` at the end of string due to you are trying to write over the array, this will cause undefined behavior.

Sometimes it is a bad idea not performing bound checking in C.